# OpenTok Audio to primary audio source in Android Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, opentok

I am creating an application using OpenTok on Ionic for Android and IOS devices.
When I am running the application on Android/IOS devices the device speaker is used as a default audio. I am struggling to use the primary audio source which we normally use when we do a phone call or whatsapp call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You would need to write a custom audio driver to be able to route the audio to the desired route. Here are some links to the sample implementations:

- [iOS - Objective-C](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/blob/master/Custom-Audio-Driver/)
- [Android - Java](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Custom-Audio-Driver)

If you're using Ionic, you would need to write a bridge via Cordova to be able to expose this functionality because it's not available through the [Cordova-Plugin-OpenTok](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok).

Comment: Thanks, @Manik but I have already moved my project to native iOS and Android from Ionic. Anyways I will try to implement this and rate your answer so that it may help others.